# Trouble in Externalizing application.properties in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, tomcat

I have a grade project with active profile stage(application-satge.properties).How can  I configure this  file from outside my project. War which is deployed in /webapps folder of tomcat, so that I can make changes since no CI/CD used in project.

**.properties files in the project

1. application.properties -> have spring.profiles.active=stage
   2.application-stage.properties

i have tried putting this content as context.xml in tomcat/conf/catalina/localhost

```
   <Context>
      <Resources>
        <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.FileResourceSet"
                base="apache-tomcat-8.5.65/webapps/application-stage.properties"
                webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes/application-stage.properties" />
      </Resources>
    </Context>
```

any suggestions please do my paths gone wrong?

Comment: If the context path of your application is, e.g. `/webApp`, you need to create `conf/Catalina/localhost/webApp.xml`. Also the value of the `base` attribute is not an absolute path.

Comment: thanks, i tried like this <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.FileResourceSet"
                base="C:/dev/apache-tomcat-8.5.65/webapps/application.properties"
                webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties" />
      </Resources>  ... changed .xml name to EmployeeLogger.xml  (name of .war) still not working